# How to loop names with spaces in bash script?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm having a python list output:

```
names=[Raj Sonakshi, Getendar, Raghu Varan (Mr)]
```

I run python script using the below bash command

```
arr=$(python names.py)
```

Output I got is:

```
Raj Sonakshi Getendar Raghu Varan (Mr)
```

When I run for loop each word is printing instead of full name:

```
for i in $arr;
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
Raj
Sonakshi
.....
.....
```

Expected Output is :

```
Raj Sonakshi
```

Comment: First of all, you forgot to post your `names.py`. Second, I suggest that you turn your shell variable `arr` into an array. While you **can** use a scalar for it, using a shell array causes much less headache, in particular if you have items with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the names in the array in quotes

```
names=["Raj Sonakshi", "Getendar", "Raghu Varan (Mr)"]
```

Comment: How to add that can you please help I'm learning now

Comment: See my updated answer above, which now includes the correction